# Getting a line that starts with a specific string in a file and compare it with another strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

It's a bit difficult to explain what I want to do but I'll try to express it clearly. I want to look for a string(url) in a file and compare it with another strings(which is named 'services' in my code),it actually needs to compare all the services with entire file 
 if the urls in the file don't include the services, do something with that url(remove that extra url from the file). 
My code is as follows but it doesn't give me correct result. I think there is something wrong with my for loops.

```
def search_service():
   status='Y'
   services = subprocess.Popen("docker-cloud service ps | awk '{print $1}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   for line in iter(services.stdout.readline, ''):
       line=line.replace("\n","")
       with open('nginx.conf') as f:
           for word in f:
              if 'proxy_pass' in word:
                   st=word
           if re.search(line,st):
              status='Y'
           else:
              status='N'
              new=st
   if 'N' in status:
      print(st)           
      #remove_block(st)
```

An example of my DockerCloud output-services:

```
dev-qwerty
test-asdfgh
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
       listen      80;
       server_name     asdfgh-test.example.com;
       location / {
          proxy_pass         http://test-asdfgh-example.io:5002/;
          proxy_redirect     off;

          ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
          blah
       }
}

 server {
       listen      80;
       server_name     nginx-dev.example.com;
       location / {
          proxy_pass         http://dev-nginx-example.io:5002/;
          proxy_redirect     off;

          ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
          blah
       }
}

server {
       listen      80;
       server_name     qwerty-dev.example.com;
       location / {
          proxy_pass         http://dev-qwerty.io:5106/;
          proxy_redirect     off;

          ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
          blah
       }
}
```

Expected output is to find out:

```
proxy_pass         http://dev-nginx-example.io:5002/;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First off, you should probably check the code you pasted, the indentation looks wrong. 
Second, it would be helpful if you could post an example of your `nginx.conf` and the output from `docker-cloud service ps | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @uvesten thanks for the comment. I've edited the question and included ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite overcomplicated, this does the same thing, and is a bit easier to read:

```
def search_service():
    services = subprocess.Popen("docker-cloud service ps | awk '{print $1}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    docker_services = []
    for line in iter(services.stdout.readline, ''):
        line=line.replace("\n","")
        docker_services.append(line)

    with open('nginx.conf') as f:
       for word in f:
            if 'proxy_pass' in word:
                unknown = True
                for service in docker_services:
                    if service in word:
                        unknown = False
                        break

                if unknown:
                    print(word.strip())
```

Comment: Ah, you wanted the services not in the output from docker. This will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great :) then I needed to use an array

Comment: That's not really the original problem... Your code will always check the _last_ service in `nginx.conf`, and if that `doesn't` match one of the docker services (which will always be true), then you print it. Check the indentation in the loops in your code to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I've understood what you're asking, but is it something along these lines?

```
dummy_input_file = 'dummy_file.in' 

with open(dummy_input_file, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write("""\
string1
string2
string3""")

expected_sub_strings = ['ing2', 'ing3']

modified_file_name = 'modified_file.out'
with open(dummy_input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(modified_file_name, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if any(s in line for s in expected_sub_strings):
            out_file.write(line)

with open(modified_file_name, 'r') as in_file:
    print(in_file.read())
```

which prints:

```
string2
string3
```

Comment: If you change the line `if any( ...` to `if not any( ...` in the above then it is what you wanted.